# How can I delete a row from a Pandas dataframe based on user input of the row's index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove a row from a dataframe, but instead of specifying the index i want the user to be able to input the row's index, and then it deletes the row based on that value

```
rowdel = input("enter row # to delete")
df.drop([rowdel], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

This is my code, but i get the error "['x'] not found in axis" (x being the input)

Comment: Try convert `rowdel` to `int` first: `df.drop([int(rowdel)], axis=0, inplace=True)`